# Shas Yidden specifics?

Tags: talmud-gemara

[Shas Yidden](http://www.shasyiden.com/) finish shas every year as explained in the numbers on their [website](http://www.shasyiden.com/). 
I’m curious for any insider or additional information on exactly what they learn and when including the reviews, daily and otherwise (and exactly how the testing works.)

**To clarify based on the comments. The website gives lots of information. What I’m looking for is what material they cover and when. (See above) that, technically speaking, if someone knew the specifics, I’d be able to implement it myself. [kind of like if I look at a DafYomi schedule I could implement that]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Somebody sent me this, it’s part of a guide made up either for the members themselves, or for fundraising purposes. The guide seems to cover a whole year.

I was also told that people have spent 10 years in the program, hopefully that puts to rest some of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The link you cite mentions that every day they learn 8 daf five times (4 chazaros), for a total of 40 daf per day. They also mention that they learn all seven days each week and overall 160 days longer than traditional kollelim. Multiplying it out, to finish 2711 daf at a rate of 8 new daf per day requires being in session for “just” 338 days each year.